# JavaScript - If statement always returning true

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have some JavaScript that I want to search for a class name in the HTML, and then detect the height of a couple elements within that div, add them together, and display the total height in an alert. The following code appears to be running perfectly, but I noticed that the code will run regardless of what the class name is, even if that class doesn't exist within the HTML. How can I rewrite the if statement so it only runs the code once it comes across a div with the specified class name? I don't want it to detect the height of the wrong h1 and p elements. Thanks for any help.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="testing">
    <h1>Understanding Scope</h1>
    <p>By understanding code's <em>scope</em>, we know when that code affects only one part of our code, or the entire codebase.  If we create things that are <em>global</em> in scope, we are giving any code the supreme power to control our code.   So we want to protect our code by being very careful when creating things that are global in scope. This is especially important if you plan on using JavaScript libraries like jQuery.</p>
</div>
<h1>Local Scope</h1>
<p>JavaScript uses <em>function scope</em>, meaning every time we create a new function the scope changes.  Any code inside that function is <em>local</em> to that function. Code that is local in scope is not accessible to outside code.</p>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function testing(){
        if (document.getElementsByClassName('testing')){
            var headerHeight = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].offsetHeight;
            var textHeight = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].offsetHeight;
            var totalHeight = headerHeight + textHeight;


            alert(totalHeight);

        }
    }
testing();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even if your document query returns an empty array, it's still `true`

This is because `[]` is a "truthy" value.

```
if ([]) { console.log("always true"); }
```

Instead try

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");

if (elems.length > 0) {
  // ...
}
```

If you don't care to access the `elems` later, you can skip the intermediate variable

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName("foo").length > 0) // ...
```

---

Per your comment

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("testing");

if (div.length > 0) {
  div[0].getElementsByTagName("h1")[0] ...
  div[0].getElementsByTagName("p")[0] ...
}
```

This will find tags within the context of `div` instead of the global `document` context.

Comment: This seems to just check whether or not that div exists and then proceeds to look for the height of the first h1 and p elements of the entire document. I want it to look for first h1 and p elements strictly from that div.

Comment: @Bryan, I've provided an edit to address your comment

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
 if (document.getElementsByClassName('testing')){ //This will always be true
```

to

```
 if (document.getElementsByClassName('testing').length){//This depends on lenght , could be 0
```

Comment: This seems to just check whether or not that div exists and then proceeds to look for the height of the first h1 and p elements of the entire document. I want it to look for first h1 and p elements strictly from that div.

Answer (score 1):

The thing here is, that you create with `document.getElementsByClassName(something)`. So the element **exists**, but it is **empty**. Therefore it has a **length 0**.

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('testa');
console.log(el); // []
```

You can **check with length**:

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName('testing').length > 0)
```

Comment: This seems to just check whether or not that div exists and then proceeds to look for the height of the first h1 and p elements of the entire document. I want it to look for first h1 and p elements strictly from that div.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use document.getElementById instead of document.getElementsByClassName.

I've seen getElementsById used in this way like so:

var elementExists = document.getElementById("targetID");

which wold be similar to what you want to do.